Property of equivalence relation $(R, X)$
I'm reading chapter IV of Categorical fundations and in one of the first remarks that is made, it is stated that given any equivalence relation $(R,X)$ in a category $\mathcal{C}$ has the property that $
R \times_{X}R {\xrightarrow{p_0} \atop \xrightarrow[p_1]{}}R$ is the kernel pair of $d_0:R \rightarrow X$, and the same with $p_1$ and $p_2$ Is the kernel pair of $d_1$. Where $(R \times_{X} R, p_0,p_2)$ is the pullback of $d_0$ along $d_1$ (so we have $d_0 \circ p_2= d_1\circ p_0$) and $p_1$ is the arrow that exist by the transitivity condition, i.e. $p_1: R\times_{X} R \to R$ satisfying  $d_0 \circ p_0 = d_0 \circ p_1$ And $d_1 \circ p_1=d_1 \circ p_2$.
I wanted to try to prove it, but to no avail. I tried to show that the square ($R \times_{X} R, p_0, p_1)$was the pullback of $d_0$ along itself, but without much success. I found some arrows given by the universal property of the pullback $(R \times_{X} R, p_0,p_2)$ but I don't understand how I can find an unique arrow $f$ from $(Y, y_0, y_1)$, where $y_i: Y \to R $ such that $d_0 \circ y_0 = d_0 \circ y_1$, to $R \times_{X} R$ such that $p_i \circ f= y_i$.
I'm sorry, but i'm not able to draw commutative diagrams with AMS (only with tikz that is not implemented in Mathjax), so the question may be difficult to read. Thanks.

With generalized elements you can reduce this to the category of sets, where it's maybe more easy for you.

Let's start by reasoning about sets for intuition, with $Y = 1$ so that we can talk about elements instead of functions. We have two elements $y_0, y_1 \in R$ with the same $d_0$, i.e. we have two pairs $(x, y)$ and $(x, z)$ with $x \sim y$ and $x \sim z$, where $\sim$ is the binary relation whose total space is $R$. We want to find an element of the pullback $R \times_X R$ of $d_0$ along $d_1$, i.e. two pairs $(x, y)$, $(y, z)$ with $x \sim y$ and $y \sim z$. We obtain $y \sim x$ by symmetry and thus $y \sim z$ by transitivity.
In a general category, we have to be a bit more explicit, but the proof internalises straightforwardly: writing $s : R \to R$ for the symmetry map and $p_1 : R \times_{d_1, d_0} R \to R$ for the transitivity map, define
$$
y_2 = p_1 \circ \langle s \circ y_0, y_1 \rangle : Y \to R
$$
where the map $\langle s \circ y_0, y_1 \rangle : Y \to R \times_{d_1, d_0} R$ is well-defined because $d_1 \circ s \circ y_0 = d_0 \circ y_0 = d_0 \circ y_1$. I now claim that the map
$$ r = \langle y_0, y_2 \rangle : Y \to R \times_{d_1, d_0} R $$
witnesses the universal property of $R \times_{d_1, d_0} R$ as the pullback of $d_0$ along itself.
First, we check that $p_0 \circ r = y_0$ and $p_1 \circ r = y_1$. The  former is immediate; for the latter, we use the fact that the map $\langle d_0, d_1 \rangle : R \to X \times X$ is a monomorphism: it suffices to check that $\langle d_0, d_1 \rangle \circ p_1 \circ r = \langle d_0, d_1 \rangle \circ y_1$, which we can do by components:
$$\begin{align}d_0 \circ p_1 \circ r &= d_0 \circ p_0 \circ r \\
&= d_0 \circ y_0 \\
&= d_0 \circ y_1\\ \\
d_1 \circ p_1 \circ r &= d_1 \circ p_2 \circ r \\
&= d_1 \circ y_2 \\
&= d_1 \circ p_1 \circ \langle s \circ y_0, y_1 \rangle \\
&= d_1 \circ p_2 \circ \langle s \circ y_0, y_1 \rangle \\
&= d_1 \circ y_1\end{align}$$
The uniqueness of this map follows by a similar argument.

So thinking in this way and generalising to Set with a $Y \neq 1$, one constructs the arrow for each element of Y. Since there are no elements (in general) in a generic category, how does the generalisation take place?

Where you would apply a function, you compose with a morphism instead. For instance, you can compose $y_0$ with the symmetry map $s : R \to R$, and then check that $s \circ y_0$ and $y_1$ together define a map $Y \to R \times_X R$ into the appropriate pullback, which you can then compose with transitivity to get a map $Y \to R$, and so on.

I tried to do that, but i found an arrow $r: Y \to R \times_{X} R$ such that $p_0 \circ r = s \circ y_0$ and $ p_2 \circ r = y_1$ that is given by the universal property of $R \times_X R $. Now how can i compose with transitivity? The only thing I have is that exists a map $p_1: R \times_ X R \to R$ such that $ d_0 \circ p_0 = d_0 \circ p_1$ and $d_1 \circ p_1= d_1 \circ p_2$. How can i use it?

Well, if you have a map $Y \to R \times_X R$ and a map $R \times_X R \to R$ you can just... compose them. After making sure that both $R \times_X R$ refer to the same pullback, of course (maybe it would be clearer to write $R \times_{d_1, d_0} R$ or something).

Yes, the pullbacks are the same one, exactly the one you said. I also understand that I have to compose the maps, but even composing them I don't know how I can prove it, because I don't know nothing about $p_1 \circ r$, do I? Sorry for the insistence and really thank you.

I've spelt out the proof in my answer now.
